# SQL Statement to copy rows of data

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

So i have a table with data that shows users and the assets they own. Each row is a different asset, so there is multiple rows for one user. Here's a sample row:

[image: Sample Row]

My question is what statement would I have to write to copy multiple rows of data from user 'AARONM' to user 'KODYM'? I believe I am over thinking it with the querys that I have tried, but I thought I would ask for outside help. Thank you in advance for your replies.

This is what I have right now:

```
 INSERT INTO Assets (USERNAME, ASSETTAG, 
    SERIALNUMBER, DEPT, CATEGORY, ITEMDESC, MODEL, ISSUEDATE, ISSUEDBY, 
    TOTALVALUE, ACCESSORIES, ISSUECONDITION, 
    NOTES, CREATEBY, CREATEDATE) 
    SELECT @USERNAME2, ASSETTAG, SERIALNUMBER, DEPT, CATEGORY, ITEMDESC, MODEL, 
    ISSUEDATE, ISSUEDBY, TOTALVALUE, ACCESSORIES, 
    ISSUECONDITION, NOTES, CREATEBY, CREATEDATE FROM ASSETS WHERE USERNAME = @USERNAME
```

Comment: @AfnanAhmad I updated the question with my current sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t(user, . . . )  -- list of columns here
    select 'KODYM', . . .  -- values for the other columns
    from t
    where user = 'AARONM';
```

Comment: will this work with all the rows of data for 'AARONM'?

Comment: If "work" means inserting all rows associated with `AARONM`, then yes.